# how can i write a string in python with comparsion

Tags: string, python-3.x, comparison, operators

I am trying to get my python to print this out but its not letting me, it keeps saying false , I want it to say  pay over time:

```
>>>     talha_hours_worked=41

>>> if talha_hours_worked > 40 :
    print("pay over time")


Print over time
>>> 
>>> talha_hours_worked>45
False
```

Comment: This code works as you expect.

Comment: `talha_hours_worked = 41`, `41>45 == false`, I don't see what you're not getting here.

Comment: Can you help me in writing  a code that will allow me to print("pay over time ") when it is greater than the hours wokrked?? I did what the gentleman write at the bottom but still it didnt work.. Thanks a lot in advance (: much apprecciated

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:Your first command is

```
talha_hours_worked = 41
```

Then, you do

```
if talha_hours_worked > 40:
    print("pay over time")
```

At this point, the value of `talha_hours_worked` is still `41`, so the if condition resolves to true, then it prints what you expect.

Your last command is

```
talha_hours_worked > 45
```

and it still has a value of 41, so this time it resolves to false. That is correct and it makes not much sense to check this.

Now, if what you want is to print that string for every value higher than 40, you should do it the opposite way. You should set your threshold in a variable

```
expected_hours = 40
```

And then check

```
if talha_hours_worked > expected_hours:
    print("pay over time")
```

This way, you can change `talha_hours_worked` to whatever value you desire, and this check will still work as you expect

Hope this helps.

Comment: then how can I adjust it so when I work over 40 hours it will print "pay over time".. Thanks for helping me out , as I am new to this (: